# How to know which user created the course in Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I'm using the Moodle database to get some information, one of which is to know the user who created a specific course. There are many tables, and I can not find the relationship between them that show which user created that course. The database management system used is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the table mdl_logstore_standard_log to get the id of the user who created the course. All actions are logged in this table.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, but has one challenge.

For larger moodle/totara deployments, the mdl_logstore_standard_log table has an admin setting on the LMS side to purge logs after a period of time to conserve application db resources.  If your instance has this feature enabled, log history will be limited.

Log data retention feature
logstore_standard | loglifetime